# What does "[got] a bird-dog on" mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

I have recently discovered the, in my view, rather splendid song *Guitar Town* by Steve Earle (released 1986). It contains the following lyric:

> Hey pretty baby are you ready for me,
>   
> It's your good rockin' daddy down from Tennessee.
>   
> I'm just out of Austin bound for San Antone
>   
> With the radio blastin' and **a bird-dog on**

Wise words, for sure, but this small town middle-class boy from the UK does not understand what it means to "have your bird-dog on"!

I have searched Urban Dictionary and other sources located through Google, and they all tell me a "bird-dog" is a man who chases other men's women, or sometimes just a man who chases *any* women. None of those explanations seem to fit with Steve Earle's meaning in Guitar Town. Unless he means that he is in the mood for chasing women, but the rest of the song is about driving from town to town putting on shows...

See also http://youtu.be/otTW0JczoGQ at around 0:19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia,  [bird-dog](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Bird_dog_(disambiguation)):

> - A bird dog can be noun which means a radar detector.(Taken from Urban dictionary) Example from Steve Earle's song "Guitar Town": "I'm just out of Austin bound for San Antone With the radio blasting and the bird dog on"

[Bird dog](http://www.radardetector.net/forums/scanners-ham-radios-cbs/55451-cb-slang.html): radar detector

( from www.radardetector.net)

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. I must admit I only skim-read Wiki and UD and I completely missed that.

Comment: You blokes are not old enough to remember the Everly Brothers *Hey bird dog get away from my quail*. They certainly didn't have radar-detectors in the late 1950s. I always took it to mean what Mrav thought it meant - i.e. a fellow who chases another fellow's 'bird'. I feel sure that Elvis also sang about a *bird-dog* too, but I can't remember the song. Try this link. Marv is right. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I65PxlOlHA4

Comment: @WS2 that song was out 4 years before I was born, though I have heard it over the years. But I have it playing as I type this, and it's great - "He's a daaawg!"

Answer (score 1):

The Bird Dog was a local radio DJ in Austin area of Texas. I asked Steve Earle this very same question a few years back in Perth Scotland.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question: if anything, it's an "I'm having this problem too" comment.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Jimmy. Unlike the earlier commentators, I think think this *does* answer the question, just not very well. Check out the [Help] to see how to write a strong answer.
Your post would be improved if it included a reference to support your assertion, and you made more effort to explicitly address the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, life long Tennessee boy here. While radar detectors are no longer worth anything because of laser technology. When this song came out everyone had one. Yes, I have heard them called bird dogs by truckers especially. Everyone I knew had one when I was younger. They were not much count unless you were on the interstate because the damn things would go off every time you passed a set of automatic doors.

Answer (score 1):

A “bird dog” on a plane is a radio directional finder.  It is (or was) used to navigate, especially to find land when over the ocean or other large bodies of water.

It was repeatedly mentioned in an episode of “Quantum Leap” called “Ghost Ship” in 1992.  They were flying through the Bermuda Triangle, and the bird dog was their only means of navigating when other instruments went crazy.

Obviously, that doesn’t apply here, unless he was homing in on a radio station in Austin, Texas (i.e., the signal was getting stronger as he got closer to the city).

https://www.flyingfishaircraftparts.com/products/aircraft-specialty-lines-rdf-2-radio-direction-finder-meter-bird-dog-asl-11933!

a Bird Dog Radio Direction Finder Meter by Aircraft Specialty Lines
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbFDh.jpg)!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kovn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The below Urban dictionary entry makes clear the meaning 'of a guy who is primarily interested in romancing another fellow's girl' - with strong reference to the Everly Brothers' song of that name:

*Hey bird dog, lay off of my quail*,

*Hey, bird dog, go chase your own tail*

See entry: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bird%20dog

*Bird dog* is also a term used in American football for a player who stares down an opponent in the way a dog stares out a bird.

Comment: Yeah I got that @WS2, but that was made me post the question, that definition doesn't fit at all well with the jist of the Guitar Town lyric, hence I realised it must have some other meaning not mentioned on UD...

Answer (score -1):

Bird dog as I know it refers to the radio disc jockey show of the era.

Radio blasting and the BIRD DOG (Disc Jockey) show is on his radio,

They way I see it as an American listening to the song, besides that's what Steve said.

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Answer (score -2):

The first four lines of "Guitar Town" are:
" Hey pretty baby are you ready for me
It's your good rockin' daddy down from Tennessee
I'm just out of Austin bound for San Antone
With the radio blastin' and the bird dog on "

The very next two lines of are:
" There's a speed trap up ahead in Selma Town
But no local yokel gonna shut me down ".

It's very clear from this context that Steve's "bird dog" slang means radar detector.
Dan in Montreal
PS
I was in Grade 11 in Toronto when the Everly Brothers "Bird Dog" went #1.
PPS
In no time!!!

Comment: That doesn't make it clear that "bird dog" means radar detector. That's just one interpretation.

Comment: There is already an [accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/215920/167396) giving this "radar detector" solution.

Comment: Steve writes in the 4th line of the song that he has "the bird dog on".

Comment: Steve writes in the 4th line of the song that he has "the bird dog on".  In the very next two lines he writes "There's a speed trap up ahead in Selma Town" and then " But no local yokel gonna shut me down ", meaning that he won't get caught in the speed trap in "Selma Town" by some state trooper because he has his radar-detector on. That is my final comment on this excruciatingly obvious subject.  Dan in Montreal